# OSX Scheduling Priorities for Newly Launched Apps

Tags: macos, performance, operating-systems, scheduling

Is it true, that OSX gives higher priority scheduling to newly launched programs? At the startup my program runs fast, but after like 10 seconds becomes a bit slower for no obvious reason (FPS drop from 80 to 70), while it should actually be faster, due to cache and page faults stabilizing. Are other operating systems (Windows and Linux) doing such creepy rescheduling?

Comment: This is highly speculative & offers no real evidence nor even solid reproducible example.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any precise documentation on OSX scheduling. So it could as well invoke a devil under the hood.